# How can I get my asp.netcore JsonResult to serialize to body inside my action controller so I can catch exceptions and time its execution?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

I have a controller action that looks like this:

```
[HttpGet]
public async Task<IActionResult> Query(CancellationToken ct, string query) 
{
  var sw = new StopWatch();
  sw.Start();

  try {
    IEnumerable<object> shortInfo = someObject.Query(query, ct).Distinct();
    return new JsonResult(
        // note that the next line still returns an IEnumerable, and does not execute yet
        // shortInfo has not yet begun enumeration either.
        shortInfo.Select(si => SomeSelectFunction(si))
    );
  }
  catch (Exception e)
  {
    return StatusCode(499);
  }
  finally
  {
    sw.Stop();
    Debug.WriteLine($"Query took {sw.ElapsedMilliseconds / 1000.0} sec");
  }
}
```

When I run my code, the time to execute is very small, and none of the enumeration has yet happened.  In addition, I cannot catch any exceptions thrown by someObject.Query due to cancellation, nor  any exceptions thrown as a result of SomeSelectFunction() which may also be quite complex.

This has the advantage that JsonResult is enumerated and serialized directly into the response body, without materializing a bunch of objects.

If instead, I change the line inside JsonResult to

```
        shortInfo.Select(si => SomeSelectFunction(si)).ToList()
```

Then I can time correctly and catch exceptions, at the cost of materializing the whole list before serializing.

**Question:** Is there any way to get the benefits of the deferred serialization, and still be able to time the total duration of the query function.  Is there a way to serialize the result to the response body inside this function and still return the json as json?

Comment: Something somewhere has to materialise the data.   Either your code does it when you say so (with the .ToList()) or the framework does it (outside of your control).  It's not magic.

Comment: That's true, but .ToList may make a list of 1 million objects, and then traverse that entire structure to generate the text for the json.  Allowing the JsonSerializer to traverse the data structure on demand doesn't require such memory pressure.

Comment: Have you tried calling `JsonConvert.Serialize(shortInfo.Select(si => SomeSelectFunction(si)))` in your function?  Have you looked at the JsonSerilzer source, to see if it does defer, or is there a ToList in there somewhere?

Comment: JsonConvert.Serialize returns a string, not json, and the current implementation of SerializeList does a foreach (object value in values) so it doesn't materialize the IEnumerable in its entirety.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider using a [Filter Implementation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/controllers/filters?view=aspnetcore-3.0), allowing you to hook into the before and after execution order. e.g.

```
   public class EndpointTimingMetricFilter : IActionFilter
   {
      public void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext context)
      {
         context.HttpContext.Items["timer"] = Stopwatch.StartNew();
      }

      public void OnActionExecuted(ActionExecutedContext context)
      {
         if (!(context.HttpContext.Items["timer"] is Stopwatch sw))
         {
            return;
         }

         sw.Stop();

         var endpointId = GetEndpointId(context);

         Debug.WriteLine($"Query took {sw.ElapsedMilliseconds / 1000.0} sec to execute for endpoint {endpointId}"); 
      }

      private static string GetEndpointId(ActionContext context)
      {
         var template = context.ActionDescriptor.AttributeRouteInfo.Template;
         var method   = context.HttpContext.Request.Method;
         return method + " - " + template;
      }
   }
```

This then gives you a cross-cutting concern that you can apply to any of your endpoints, and keeps this boiler plate code out of your main controller actions.

OnActionExecuted is after the result/response is built, so should give you what you're after,

[image]

Image from: https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/working-with-filters-in-asp-net-core-mvc/

Comment: Thanks.  That will probably solve the timing issue.  Any suggestions on how to catch the exceptions?

Comment: For the timing filter, you have access to an Exception object on the context in the filter, so can make decisions about what to do in exceptional cases there if you like (i.e. only time successful responses). For all other exceptions, have a look at an implementation of ExceptionFilterAttribute that can give you a consistent response from all your API endpoints, e.g. a 500 error with some JSON payload. Filters in general are the way to hook into the pipeline and customise the behaviour